# Finding previous month end date

Tags: r, date, seq, chron

From date 10/31/2018, I want to obtain 09/30/2018.

I tried:

```
PREV.PROD.DATE<-seq.Date(from=as.Date(chron("10/31/2018")),length=2,by="-1 months")
```

but it returns:

> "2018-10-31" "2018-10-01"

How can I obtain 09/30 instead of 10/01?

Notes: I would like to avoid to use an external package, and I would like the solution to work for any end of month date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to `floor` the date - making it the first day of its month, and then subtract 1 to make it the last day of the previous month:

```
x = as.Date("2018-10-31")
library(lubridate)
floor_date(x, unit = "months") - 1
# [1] "2018-09-30"
```

---

Here's a version without using other packages:

```
as.Date(format(x, "%Y-%m-01")) - 1
# [1] "2018-09-30"
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to avoid to load a new package, because this code line is to be integrated in a big project.

Comment: Perfectly understandable. Don't take new dependencies lightly! I'd recommend editing your question to be more specific about your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

The integer units of `Date` are days, so you can do:

```
seq.Date(from=as.Date("2018-10-31"), length=2, by="-1 months") - c(0,1)
# [1] "2018-10-31" "2018-09-30"
```

If you want arbitrary prior-last-date:

```
(d <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()))
# [1] "2018-11-08 UTC"
d$mday <- 1L
as.Date(d) - 1
# [1] "2018-10-31"
```

Replace `Sys.Date()` with whatever single date you have. If you want to vectorize this:

```
(ds <- Sys.Date() + c(5, 20, 50))
# [1] "2018-11-13" "2018-11-28" "2018-12-28"
lapply(as.POSIXlt(ds), function(a) as.Date(`$<-`(a, "mday", 1L)) - 1L)
# [[1]]
# [1] "2018-10-31"
# [[2]]
# [1] "2018-10-31"
# [[3]]
# [1] "2018-11-30"
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that it has to work for any end of month date...

Comment: Wow, that was a quick downvote. BladeVsResiduals, I don't know precisely what you mean. My code does precisely what you posed in your question, can you fix your question to better reflect what you mean here?

Comment: If you're referring to `lubridate::mday`, OP stated their preference against external packages.

Comment: @r2evans This is a cool answer with `function(a) as.Date(`$<-`(a, "mday", 1L)) - 1L` without any external packages, Learn it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use function `chron`. But I think the function `duration` from `lubridate` helps you.
You don't need use `floor_date` to confuse you.

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> 载入程辑包：'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
library(tidyverse)
better_date <- 
    str_split("10/31/2018",'/') %>% 
    .[[1]] %>% 
    .[c(3,1,2)] %>% 
    str_flatten(collapse = '-') %>% 
    as.Date()
(better_date - duration('1 months')) %>% 
    as.Date()
#> [1] "2018-09-30"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: That assignment of `better_date` can much more easily be handled with `as.Date(..., format="%m/%d/%Y")`, why go through all of that trouble? It's a bit obfuscated and inefficient (IMO). The gem of this is in the last 2 lines of code ... unfortunately the OP commented in another answer that they don't want non-base packages ...

Comment: Yeah ... Just a quick answer, because I am more familiar with tidyverse than the base packages, I think your answer is better a lot!